# id3v2 - cli unable to add image

Tags: mp3, id3v2

Using [id3v2](http://id3v2.sourceforge.net/) to add information to MP3 files, but I don't seem to be able to add the image using the `--APIC` flag, it doesn't fail but it doesn't add it either.

Info: running Ubuntu 14.04LTS & id3v2 (installed via apt-get);

```
id3v2 0.1.12
Uses id3lib-3.8.3
```

Here is the command I am running: `id3v2 --APIC image.jpg ../tracks/track.mp3`

Looking through the docs that looks to be accurate, but I am not getting the image added, so unable to see the album artwork in something like iTunes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, id3v2 cannot embed images in mp3 files.

Looking at the [source](http://sourceforge.net/p/id3v2/git/ci/7523fa9e308b853834020aba883897f2ddf2c205/tree/id3v2.cpp#l636), it only prints information to the console,
without doing anything else.

Comment: Oh, I thought I would be able to add the image to mp3 file so that it would be used as the artwork. Is there no way to add the artwork/packshot to a file so that is viewable via something like iTunes? Thanks @SMeyer

Comment: Not with id3v2, but there are multiple tools that should be able to do that. See for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84915/add-album-art-cover-to-mp3-ogg-file-from-command-line-in-batch-mode